# World practice to secure web forms from spam

Tags: forms, security, web, spam, spam-prevention

We have some competitors to our e-commerce website, and we're getting hundreds of spam orders with multiple techniques.

Note that: we have pay on delivery option, that's why can't check online payment if money arrived or not.

We tried following ways to secure order form from spam orders but nothing helps:

- Google Recaptcha 2: They use both human and bot power to skip it
- SMS verification: they use android phones to programmatically get sms code and fill our form
- IP blocking: they use VPN all over the world skip it
- Email verification: easyly skippable both by bots and humans

Is there any other way to detect spam from real? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're not trying to detect spam, you're trying to make sure you get paid.

This is a business-process issue, not a software issue.

What's broken isn't your website it's your business process.

You need to either:

- Get paid up front
- Get a credit card at the time of the order.Tell the user you'll be putting a hold on the card for the amount of the order, but that they'll only be charged after delivery.

This will ensure that at the very least your customer is *able* and probably willing to pay. When you deliver, put the charge through.

Other that that, you're out of luck. You can't just ship out merchandise and hope you get paid. Because you won't.

You don't care if the fake orders are human or not. It's just as easy for a real person to give you a fake order as for a bot to do it.